# how hide/show div depending on days using javascript or php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to show div only Sunday Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday

and hide it in ,Friday,Saturday

this my code:

```
<script>
function newep(){
var fecha = new date();
var day = fecha.getDay();
if(day == 4 || day == 5){
 console.log("show nothing");
}else if(day == 6 || day == 3){
 console.log("New Episodde");
}
}
</script>
```

```
<div onload="newep()">here the output</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that out of your code:

````
<script>
function newep(node)
{
var fecha = new date();
var day = fecha.getDay();
if(day == 4 || day == 5){
 node.hidden=true;
 //or : node.disabled=true
}
}
</script>

```<div onload="newep(this)">here the output</div>```
````

with php you could do:

```
<?php
$date_number=date('w');
if($date_number==5 || $date_number==6)
{
 ?>
 //your div
 <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: wen i use the php version i get error  ----> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "if" in

Comment: forgot the ; after $date_number=date('w') my bad

Comment: i need exacly like this can you tel me were is the error:   <?php
$date_number=date('w');
if($date_number==0 || $date_number==4)
{
 ?>
<span class="types types-new">Nuevo</span>
 <?php
}
?>
<?php else($date_number==5 || $date_number==6){?>
<span class="types types-new">caducado</span>
<?php } ?>

Comment: you forgot an if just after else there 
<?php $date_number = date('w');
if ($date_number == 0 || $date_number == 4)
{ ?> 
    <span class="types types-new">Nuevo</span> 
<?php
} 
else if($date_number == 5 || $date_number == 6)
{ ?> 
    <span class="types types-new">caducado</span> 
<?php
} ?>